# Bug in user page layout on IE7?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When I go to a user page with IE7 the layout is not correct.

Does anyone else see this?

Update: notice how I can't scroll to the left to see the full page.
IE7 version 7.0.5730.13.CO

[image]

Comment: Mine looks fine, xp service pack 3 and ie7, mind posting a pic of the problem?

Comment: I see, I thought you were talking about this page at first, http://gis.stackexchange.com/users . Mine is acting funny as well, and it appears to be the same problem.

Comment: @andy Thanks, pls upvote to get SE's attention.

Comment: @Kirk sorry forgot to upvote! Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: +1, same issue in IE 8, XP Pro, sp3.  Works fine in firefox

Comment: @kirk I'm looking into this problem. I'm able to reproduce it in IE9 running IE7 mode. I'm curious, did you always have this problem in IE7 since the new design launched, or is this something more recent?

Answer (score 2):

IE 9 is fine.  No help unless you plan to upgrade, but an FYI for others.

Answer (score 1):

I generally run ie in compatibility view which is when the css (im assuming) issue seems to be occuring.  The page displays correctly for me when compatibility mode is toggled off.  Not excactly a proper fix, but figured i would mention.

Answer (score 0):

The fix will be in the next deployment.